# Does --pickaxe-regex really enable POSIX extended?

Tags: git, posix, git-log

I'm disappointed by the `--pickaxe-regex` behavior in Git 2.43.
The [diffcore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitdiffcore#_diffcore_pickaxe_for_detecting_additiondeletion_of_specified_string) claims the following (emphasis mine):

> "-S<block of text>" detects filepairs whose preimage and postimage have different number of occurrences of the specified block of text. By definition, it will not detect in-file moves. Also, when a changeset moves a file wholesale without affecting the interesting string, diffcore-rename kicks in as usual, and `-S` omits the filepair (since the number of occurrences of that string didn’t change in that rename-detected filepair). **When used with `--pickaxe-regex`, treat the <block of text> as an extended POSIX regular expression to match,** instead of a literal string.

But that doesn't seem to be accurate. I've been comparing the output of these test commands in a Python repository:

```bash
# Success: just text in the search block
git log --pickaxe-regex -S'def'

# Broken on MacOS: POSIX extended word boundaries
git log --pickaxe-regex -S'\bdef\b'
git log --pickaxe-regex -S'\<def\>'
# But success on Git for Windows
```

The `\b`-wrapping doesn't require `def` to begin and end [with word boundaries](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/basic_extended.html#boost_regex.syntax.basic_extended.word_boundaries). It just breaks the search so that no results are returned. Just in case there is some confusion about escaping, I have also tried `-S'\\bdef\\b'`, `-S"\bdef\b"`, and `-S"\\bdef\\b"`. None of them return results, but `-S'def'` does.

What's going on here?

Comment: I don't think `\b` means a word boundary in extended POSIX regular expressions. Reference: [POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions)

Comment: @topsail I was looking at [the GNU docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/posix_002dextended-regular-expression-syntax.html), but maybe I just misunderstood what "extensions" meant. Edit: [Boost also thinks](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/basic_extended.html#boost_regex.syntax.basic_extended.word_boundaries) that `\b` is okay.

Comment: Hmmm ... okay I don't really know.

Comment: @topsail You were right. Boost nonchalantly puts this line in the middle of the page, with **no emphasis whatsoever:** _"However, that's rather restrictive, so the following standard-compatible extensions are also supported by Boost.Regex:"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\b` is not defined by POSIX.  It's an extension that is present in Perl, Ruby, and PCRE.

From `regex(7)` on Linux:

> Regular expressions ("RE"s), as defined in POSIX.2, come in two forms: modern REs (roughly those of egrep; POSIX.2 calls these "extended" REs) and obsolete REs (roughly those of ed(1); POSIX.2 "basic" REs).

POSIX extended REs support `|`, `+`, `*`, `?`, `^`, `$` and bounds (with braces). They also support brackets with character classes.

Again, from `regex(7)`:

> Obsolete ("basic") regular expressions differ in several respects.  '|', '+', and '?' are ordinary characters and there is no equivalent for their functionality.  The delimiters for  bounds  are  "{"
> and  "}",  with  '{'  and  '}' by themselves ordinary characters.  The parentheses for nested subexpressions are "(" and ")", with '(' and ')' by themselves ordinary characters.  '^' is an ordinary
> character except at the beginning of the RE or(!) the beginning of a parenthesized subexpression, '$' is an ordinary character except at the end of the RE or(!) the end of a  parenthesized  subexpres‐
> sion, and '*' is an ordinary character if it appears at the beginning of the RE or the beginning of a parenthesized subexpression (after a possible leading '^').

All other escapes and functionality are basically defined by Perl or PCRE (including normal C escapes, like `\t` and `\n`).  I don't believe there's an option to use PCRE in the pickaxe functionality, so you'll need to either send a patch or stick to extended POSIX regexes.

Answer (score 0):

[The answer from bk2204](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77629214/241211) is correct for making POSIX.2-compatible portable scripts. However, on *your local system,* you seem to get whatever the OS decides "extended" regular expressions contain, including whatever extensions it bundles.

Consult `regex(7)` and/or `re_format(7)` to see what yours does.

| Regular Expression | MacOS | Git for Windows |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `def` | ✓ | ✓ |
| `\bdef\b` |  | ✓ |
| `\<def\>` |  | ✓ |
| `[[:<:]]def[[:>:]]` | ✓ | (fatal) |
| `def[[:blank:]]` | ✓ | ✓ |